# Why do I get "Could not find gdlib-config in the search path" when I try to install GD::Polygon, even though gdlib-config is installed?

Tags: perl, gd, cpan, gdlib

I'm trying to install [GD::Polygon](https://metacpan.org/pod/GD::Polygon) by running `cpan install GD::Polygon`, but I get the following error:

```
**UNRECOVERABLE ERROR**
Could not find gdlib-config in the search path. Please install libgd 
2.0.28 or higher.
```

I manually installed libgd-2.2.1 from source (`./configure`, `make`, `make install`) and now when I run `whereis gdlib-config`, I see that it is indeed installed:

```
gdlib-config: /usr/local/bin/gdlib-config
```

How can I tell `cpan` where to find this library?

Comment: Is `gdlib-config` in your `PATH`?

Comment: also... did you try in a new terminal window to ensure PATH was updated accordingly?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot /usr/local/bin is in my PATH... should I specifically include gdlib-config too ?

Comment: mh, I got the error message in my description from running "sudo cpan install GD::Polygon". When i try without sudo, it does not complain about it anymore but then I get another error message from cpan

Comment: @FloranGmehlin With `sudo`, you're running as a different user (root), so the `PATH` is different. Personally, I would recommend only using your system's package manager (e.g. yum, apt-get) to install modules in the system perl; use something like perlbrew to install your own local copies of perl.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot oops, forget my last comment, when I run it without sudo, it does try to install it but at the end the message still shows up (was a bit difficult to spot)

Comment: @stevieb well, I added gdlib-config in the $PATH, but when I open a new Terminal window $PATH is not updated

Comment: Ok, it seems that adding gdlib-config to the PATH solved it. Now I have other errors from cpan itself. Thank you guys for your help

Comment: perhaps try a symlink? `sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/gdlib-config/gdlib-config /usr/local/bin/gdlib-config`... nevermind, your comment about it being fixed came up as I entered this comment.

Comment: @FloranGmehlin Great! Please add an answer showing what you did to solve it so other people with the same problem can see without having to read through all the comments.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Sure, will do that :) However, another question shows up. The error I mentioned after solving the gdlib thing probably comes from the fact that I need to sudo install it. Now, when I try to sudo install it, it does not find gdlib-config again (even though I added it in the PATH and in ~/.bashrc). any thought ?

Comment: 1) In general, I think it's best not to install things to the system perl with cpan, which is what you're trying to do by running `sudo cpan`; you should either use a package manager like yum, or install a local perl with something like perlbrew. What OS are you running? 2) Your user's `PATH` is not the same as root's `PATH`, and your `.bashrc` is not the same as root's `.bashrc`.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I see. I'm running on Linux RHEL7. I actually only need these Libraries to install a software for machine translation... I will not use perl otherwise. Should I still install a local perl ? I also tried with yum but could not manage to install what I needed.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot oh gee. yum indeed did the trick. this cpan brought me more problems than anything else... I will write an answer accordingly, thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, short answer is : I installed GD via `yum` instead of `cpan`.

```
sudo yum install perl-GD
```

If you still want to install it through `cpan`, you should include `gdlib-config` on your PATH (not just the folder e.g. `/usr/local/bin` or wherever it is).

Installing Perl packages with `yum` is definitively better than with `cpan`

Comment: `yum` (and `apt-get`) have an advantage over `cpan` for Perl modules that need to be integrated with non-Perl libraries, as they can manage the dependencies and install pre-compiled objects that are tested and known to be compatible on your system. You give up the flexibility of working with non-system `perl`s or modifying the module's source, if you're into that sort of thing.

Comment: I can't get this to work with apt-get: `apt-get install perl-GD`, gives:  E: Unable to locate package perl-GD . I can't believe how  hard it's proving to get this server setup, using later versions of Perl :/

Comment: @AndrewNewby: You are looking for `sudo apt-get install libgd-gd2-perl`

Answer (score 1):

I agree to go for using the package manager.
You do not mention which OS you use.
On Ubuntu Linux, /usr/local/bin is also in the path of the root user.
You can double check if the file is executable.

Also make sure the script that does the Perl compiling does not mess up the PATH variable.

I am using perlbrew and do not run as root, using cpan to install things.
Note: on Ubuntu 16.10 and 17.04 gdlib-config is missing, because debian maintainers seem to have removed it.

To get it, you can compile the source here:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libgd2_2.1.1.orig.tar.gz

with the following patch applied:

```
diff webpimg.c.org libgd-gd-2.1.1-patched-16.10plus/src/webpimg.c
714c714
<     vpx_img_wrap(&img, IMG_FMT_I420,
---
>     vpx_img_wrap(&img, VPX_IMG_FMT_I420,
716,721c716,721
<     img.planes[PLANE_Y] = (uint8*)(Y);
<     img.planes[PLANE_U] = (uint8*)(U);
<     img.planes[PLANE_V] = (uint8*)(V);
<     img.stride[PLANE_Y] = y_stride;
<     img.stride[PLANE_U] = uv_stride;
<     img.stride[PLANE_V] = uv_stride;
---
>     img.planes[VPX_PLANE_Y] = (uint8*)(Y);
>     img.planes[VPX_PLANE_U] = (uint8*)(U);
>     img.planes[VPX_PLANE_V] = (uint8*)(V);
>     img.stride[VPX_PLANE_Y] = y_stride;
>     img.stride[VPX_PLANE_U] = uv_stride;
>     img.stride[VPX_PLANE_V] = uv_stride;
```

cheers

Answer (score 1):

By the way, it seems that CPAN installer just needs a "devel" version of libgd to build the package. I tryed to install it on an old cygwin plateform and finaly it works with the "libgd-devel" component.

Answer (score 1):

I tried using the following code to install the libbgd. After I add the libgd-2.2.5/bin path to `$PATH`, it works.

```
wget https://github.com/libgd/libgd/releases/download/gd-2.2.5/libgd-2.2.5.tar.gz
tar zxvf libgd-2.2.5.tar.gz
cd libgd-2.2.5
./configure -prefix=/home/yourname/local
make
make install
make installcheck
```